# Redirect after webform submission inside a colorbox node, doesnt work

Tags: 7, webforms, rules, redirection, javascript

I have a webform inside a [colorbox node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node), shows nicely, submits...
But, both the built in redirect in webform and rules redirect is ignored and the modal stays stubbornly open. **And no redirect happens.**

Furthermore inside my rule i also set a status msg which never shows.

I do know that the rule is triggered because it also creates a new entity on submissions and sets values from webform to a node. And this part of rules actions happens ok... There is no errors in the log either...

The module i use: [colorbox_node module](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node)

Please help... :) Thanks in advance...

Comment: For the rule that has the redirect action, what event is triggering the rule. Are there any conditions set for this rule?

Comment: the rule has a condition that its the form with name "x", but as i mentioned the rule is triggered as witnessed by the fact that other things in the action list are being done fine...